# Array indexing: the fastest way to replace the indexes with another set of indexes in python

Tags: python

I have the values and the corresponding old indexes

```
import random
import numpy as np

values = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(5,))
old_indexes = np.array(random.sample(range(1, 100), 5)) # same size as "values"
list_of_old_indexes = np.random.choice(old_indexes, size=(20,)) # the size could be very large (>1M)
```

After running the example code, I have:

```
>>> values
array([0.43533591, 0.37287051, 0.58961606, 0.42598503, 0.22623544])
>>> old_indexes
array([91, 11, 46, 93, 17])
>>> list_of_old_indexes
array([91, 91, 11, 17, 11, 46, 11, 93, 91, 91, 46, 17, 17, 17, 91, 93, 11, 91, 17, 91])
```

Now I want to replace the `old_indexes` with `new_indexes`

```
new_indexes = np.arange(5)
```

It is the natural indexing of the array `values`. Comparing the `old_indexes` and the `new_indexes`, we have

```
>>> old_indexes
array([91, 11, 46, 93, 17])
>>> new_indexes
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

How could I efficiently replace in the `list_of_old_indexes` all `91` to `0`, `11` to `1`, `46` to `2`, and so on, and get the results of the `list_of_new_indexes` like this:

```
>>> list_of_new_indexes
array([0, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 4, 0, 3, 1, 0, 4, 0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a dictionary mapping old indices to new indices

```
old_to_new = dict(zip(old_indexes,new_indexes))
```

Create a vectorize function with that dictionary and call it on your old indices

```
vec_func = np.vectorize(lambda x: old_to_new[x])
vec_func(list_of_old_indexes)
```

output:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 4, 0, 3, 1, 0, 4, 0])
```